# Wordpress page content not displaying

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I set up a wordpress site with a splash page but none of the content appears on the site once you click through to a page

http://www.dawaf.co.uk/es/

http://www.dawaf.co.uk/es/fashion-beauty

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasRegular';
    src: url('fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.svg#BebasRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    border: 0;
    font-family: BebasRegular;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

#page {
    margin: 100px 0 0 0;
    background: transparent;
}

body {
    background: #FFF;
}

/*Menu
------------------------------------------------------------ */
#access div {
    margin: 0px;
}

#access {
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 185px;
    margin: 0px 20px 6px;
    position: relative;
    top: -65px;
    left: 6px;
}

#access ul {
    font-size: 12px;
}

#access a {
    color: #737373;
    line-height: 27px !important;
}

#access li:hover > a, #access a:focus {
    background: transparent;
}

#access .current-menu-item > a, #access .current-menu-ancestor > a, #access .current_page_item > a, #access .current_page_ancestor > a {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
}

/*Header
------------------------------------------------------------ */
#branding {
    border-top: none;
}

.logo {
    width: 300px;
    height: 132px;
    top: -100px;
    position: relative;
    left: 8px;
}

/*Splash Page
------------------------------------------------------------ */
body.home.page.page-id-17 nav#access {
    display: none;
}

#branding #searchform {
    display: none;
}

#colophon {
    display: none;
}

.nopassword, .nocomments {
    display: none;
}
```

The splash page is set up in the header.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html id="ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html id="ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<title><?php
    /*
     * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
     */
    global $page, $paged;

    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyeleven' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    ?></title>

<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php
    /* We add some JavaScript to pages with the comment form
     * to support sites with threaded comments (when in use).
     */
    if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

    /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
     * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
     */
    wp_head();
?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed">
    <header id="branding" role="banner">

            <?php
                // Check to see if the header image has been removed
                $header_image = get_header_image();
                if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) :
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                <?php
                    // The header image
                    // Check if this is a post or page, if it has a thumbnail, and if it's a big one
                    if ( is_singular() &&
                            has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) &&
                            ( /* $src, $width, $height */ $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array( HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH, HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) ) ) &&
                            $image[1] >= HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) :
                        // Houston, we have a new header image!
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail' );
                    else : ?>
                    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>" height="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>" alt="" />
                <?php endif; // end check for featured image or standard header ?>
            </a>
            <?php endif; // end check for removed header image ?>

            <?php
                // Has the text been hidden?
                if ( 'blank' == get_header_textcolor() ) :
            ?>
                <div class="only-search<?php if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?> with-image<?php endif; ?>">
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php
                else :
            ?>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

<div class="logo"><img src="http://www.dawaf.co.uk/es/wp-content/themes/child/images/es-logo.png"></div>

            <nav id="access" role="navigation">
                <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Main menu', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
                <?php /*  Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff. */ ?>
                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
                <?php /* Our navigation menu.  If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu. The menu assiged to the primary position is the one used. If none is assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used. */ ?>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
            </nav><!-- #access -->
    </header><!-- #branding -->


    <div id="main">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check putting, just change and see position,

```
#branding {
  z-index:0;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: @user1096057 change and see the position of #branding .. more chance for that

Answer (score 0):

Answer is below, its working for me when i do it in firebug

```
#access{
 display: block !important;
}
```